# How to use regex c++?

Tags: c++, regex, search, match

I've got a problem with c++ regex.
I've got a string like "f 123/123 1234/123/124 12" and I want to get all the numbers before "/".

This is my regexp:

> "\s(\d+)".

I tried it on http://rubular.com/ and it works.
Here is my code:

```
std::regex rgx("\\s(\\d+)");
std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_search(line, match, rgx))
{
    std::cout << "Match\n";

    std::string *msg = new std::string();
    std::cout << "match[0]:" << match[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "match[1]:" << match[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << "match[2]:" << match[2] << "\n";

}
```

But I get this:

> Match
>   match[0]:123
>   match[1]:123
>   match[2]:

I realize that `match[0]` is not a "groups" like in Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regex_search` matches once (the first substring that match the regular expression). You need to loop.

Try following:

```
std::regex rgx("\\s(\\d+)");
std::smatch match;

while (std::regex_search(line, match, rgx))
{
    std::cout << match[0] << std::endl;
    line = match.suffix().str();
}
```

Comment: @suspectus, See [`match_resulsts::suffix`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/suffix/) and [`match_resulsts::str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/str/).

Comment: @suspectus, Sorry, I misunderstood. You meant a typo. I fixed it. Thank you for pointing that.